# SVN propset svn:externals Error

Tags: svn

I am trying to set the external to a specific revision via command line.  Earlier I got an error indicating that I needed to use the working directory when I used the repository URL for both my source and destination.  I changed the destination folder to my working directory.  I do not want to have the externed folder added to my working directory(seems it should be unnecessary).

Notes:

- http replaced with htp to avoid hyperlinks.
- htps://svn.company.com/svn/Build = location of the externed folder
- C:/Subversion/Build/Tool = folder where the svn property 'svn:externals' is set

Here is my syntax:

svn propset svn:externals -- "-r611 htp://svn.company.com/svn/Build" "C:/Subversion/Build/Tool"

Here is the error I get:
svn: E195005:

Error parsing svn:externals property on 
'C:/Subversion/Build/Tool: '-r611 htp://svn.company.com/svn/Build

Any help with syntax/ cause of error is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

1. External folder's content will not appear in  your WC until you will not perform `svn up` after defining externals
2. You **must** to read at least `svn help ps` (in the part of externals format)
3. You miss at least one mandatory parameter and wrongly define second

For command

```
WC>svn propset svn:externals "https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/customlocations-greylink/trunk/Local Data" .
```

where WC is root of Working copy of repository-trunk I defined directory subdir Data (not existing before as real folder in tree) of current dir (.) as container for HEAD-revision for content of directory `/trunk/Local` from external repo

In case of fixed external `-r NNN` have to be added in front of URL

**Full command**

`svn propset svn:externals "-r611 htp://svn.company.com/svn/Build" Build/Tool`

must map htp://svn.company.com/svn/Build at the revision 611 to folder Build/Tool in repo-folder, linked to your WC (`/trunk` ?)

Easier form is writing value of svn:externals into file and using -F option in propset. If externals.txt contain string

`-r611 htp://svn.company.com/svn/Build`

(without double quotes here)

`svn propset svn:externals -F externals.txt Build/Tool`

will produce the same result as the above command. Added value - for permanent path you can always use the same command and change only extermal text-file

Comment: 1. Check. ( I ran svn proplist ".\trunk" and it returned svn:externals) <--this is the root of my WC. Here is my new command(executed within root of WC (where external resides)): svn propset svn:externals -r611 "htp://svn.company.com/svn/Build Build/Tool". I get the error "cannot specify revision for setting versioned property 'svn:externals'". NOTE: in the path in quotes, I can see that directly from my external definition within tortoise svn(from clicking on the trunk folder of my WC)

Comment: @user3555181 - please surround command with ` signs in order to improve visibility and you misplace first " - `-r611` is part of external property value and must be inside " - `svn propset svn:externals "-r611 htp://svn.company.com/svn/Build" Build/Tool` . command added to answer also for readability

Answer (score -1):

Uh, did you mean htp or http? Because I see htp. Maybe that's causing the problem.